# Determine if target entity is a foreign key in Doctrine filter

Tags: doctrine-orm

Doctrine passes a `$targetEntity` and `$targetTableAlias` to the filter constraint like so:

```
public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias)
{ ...
```

It appears that all entities pass through the filter when a query is being built.  Is there any way to determine if `$targetEntity` is a foreign key or not?  I'd like to write a filter that works on the "primary" entity (what Doctrine calls the "base" table) but not its foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear and I am not sure if this will answer your question, but in [the Doctrine 2 documentation chapter **30. Filters**](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/filters.html#filters) you can read the following:

> In the case of joined or single table inheritance, you always get passed the ClassMetadata of the inheritance root. This is necessary to avoid edge cases that would break the SQL when applying the filters.

So I would say the `$targetEntity` is always the root entity (so never a foreign key).

If this doesn't answer your question I would like to ask you to be a bit more specific on what exactly you want to do or what you want to find out.

Comment: Thanks for this. As far as I can tell from actual Doctrine behavior, all entities get passed through the filter, including foreign keys. I can kind of determine what is what based on the `$targetTableAlias`, but I'm not quite clear on how that is generated.